# Router + Modem Device Not Connecting to Modem

Tags: networking, router, modem

Current setup which works perfect;

- RJ11 Cable plugs into;
- Netgear D7000v2 (Modem + Router combo) - ISP settings on here - Default IP, 192.168.0.1
- Which plugs into PC
- Internet connects fine

New setup I'm testing, which isn't working. The Netgear D7000v2 won't connect to the internet. Setup;

- RJ11 Cable plugs into;
- DrayTek Vigor 130 Modem - Configured in Bridge Mode - Default IP, 192.168.2.1
- RJ45 Cable from above device into Ethernet WAN port on;
- Netgear D7000v2 (Modem + Router combo) - ISP settings on here - Default IP, 192.168.0.1 (no config change here from working setup above
- Showing in Netgear D7000v2 Admin Console as not connect to internet

From the vast research I did before purchasing the DrayTek Vigor 130 modem, it appeared to be virtually a plug and play setup with just the bridge mode requiring to be configured on the DrayTek Vigor 130 modem.

Since this didn't work, I've since updated the Netgear D7000v2 settings to specifically set it to use WAN Over Ethernet. Still no difference, no internet.

Two theories at the moment;

1. Something to do with the DrayTek (192.168.2.1) and Netgear (192.168.0.1) being on different subnets which is causing issues. Although I thought that was the whole point of bridge mode on the DrayTek, to jump between the subnets.

Update: Just tested this theory, and changed the IP address on the DrayTek to 192.168.0.2 so they are on the same subnet. Same issue, the Netgear D7000v2 won't connect to the internet. Looks like my second theory may be correct. Doesn't appear that the Netgear D7000v2 is capable of working with a separate modem in bridge mode.

2. Netgear D700v2 is just a bit naff and can't work in Router Only mode. I've found a setting in the admin console which only lists the following options for Device Mode: Modem Only. Router + Modem.

Thoughts on options to try?

I'm ultimately going to be getting rid of the Netgear D7000v2 as I've encountered other problems with it not supporting basic nat loopback (to be replaced with pfSense). But rather than replacing all hardware at once I wanted to take the step by step approach to replace one item at a time.

Comment: If the DrayTek is truly in bridge mode you should be able to go in to the Netgear and see the IP address picked up from the ISP. You should also be able to release and renew. That being said I have Comcast and every time I put on a new router I have to do two things. 1) Register the MAC address with Comcast and 2) Have them do a DHCP release. It could be that your ISP has locked on to the Netgear and you need to have them release it so the DrayTek can pick up the IP.

Comment: Glad I'm not going mad missing something blindingly obvious :-) I've got another router+modem lying around which I could do with testing the same setup on to see if that makes a difference. Also got an open ticket with ISP to see if there is anything at their end too.

Answer (score -1):

Plugged a different Modem + Router in so the Netgear D7000v2 wasn't being used. And magically this just worked. Another nail in the coffin for the Netgear D7000v2, failing on basic things yet again.

Comment: I do love Stack* .... Some numpty down voting an Answer I have given to help others off the back of my Own Question. I'm sure there is some IdiotAI on Stack* that just likes to downvote things for a laugh. Perhaps this is still just non-AI involved at this stage... ;-)